# Jira scriptrunner script field: on a custom field, calculate value of other custom fields and display total

Tags: groovy, jira

I am trying to create a custom field that displays the calculated value of 4 other custom fields.

I need to get the field, get the value, change the value to an integer (they are single select fields) and then calculate the fields value.

Here is the code I have that isn't working:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue


def bvField = ComponentAccessor().getCustomFieldManager().getCustomfFieldObjectbyName("BV")
def bvValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(bvfield)
def tcField = ComponentAccessor().getCustomFieldManager().getCustomfFieldObjectbyName("TC")
def tcValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(tcField)
def rrField = ComponentAccessor().getCustomFieldManager().getCustomfFieldObjectbyName("RR")
def rrValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(rrField)
def jobSizeField = ComponentAccessor().getCustomFieldManager().getCustomfFieldObjectbyName("Job Size Field")
def jobSizeValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(jobSizeField)

def jobSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(jobSizeValue)
def rrInt = Integer.parseInt(rrValue)
def tcInt = Integer.parseInt(tcValue)
def bvInt = Integer.parseInt(bvValue)

def total = (bvInt + tcInt + rrInt) / jobSizeInt


if (bvValue!="none" && tcValue!="none" && rrValue!="none" && jobSizeValue!="none") {
    return total
    } else {
    return 85
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the lines

```
def jobSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(jobSizeValue)
def rrInt = Integer.parseInt(rrValue)
def tcInt = Integer.parseInt(tcValue)
def bvInt = Integer.parseInt(bvValue)
```

with

```
def jobSizeInt = jobSizeValue.toInteger()
def rrInt = rrValue.toInteger()
def tcInt = tcValue.toInteger()
def bvInt = bvValue.toInteger()
```